# why isn't my program not showing nested if and else in the shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Still can't figure why Grande will run through completely through but executive and junior won't? I've tried removing the return but then that causes the if statements to run into each other.

```
    def main(): # program is too ask subject about the hotel room he wants
    yes = "yes"    #Also calculate the cost of it 
    yes1 = "yes "
    no = "no"
    no1 = "no "
    discount = .2
    print("Welcome to Flappies Hotel!")
    print("With a *three* night stay we will take 20% off your purchase.") 
    print("The suites we have available are the Junior, Executive, and Grande.")
    print("The Grande suite runs at 350.00 a night.")
    grande = input("Would you like the Grande suite? ")
    if grande == yes or yes1 : #yes1 incase the user puts a space after the yes
        grande = 350.00
    else:
        grande1 = int(float(input("How many nights do you intend to stay? ")))
        grande2 = (grande*grande1)
        if grande1 == 3.0 :
            grande_total = (grande*grande1*discount)
            grande = float(grande2-grande_total)
            grande_fin = format(grande, '.2f')
            print("Your total purchase will be",grande_fin,",enjoy your stay at Flappies.")
            return #used to cut off the if statement so it wont continue on
        else:  
            grande = 350.00  
            grande_total = float(grande*grande1)
            grande_fin = format(grande_total, '.2f')
            print("Your total purchase will be",grande_fin,",enjoy your stay at Flappies.")
            return


    print("The Executive suite runs 250.00 a night.")
    executive = input("Would you like the Executive suite? ")
    yes = "yes"
    yes1 = "yes "
    no = "no"
    no1 = "no "
    discount = .2 
    if executive == yes or yes1 :
        executive = 250.00
    else:
        executive1 = int(float(input("How many nights do you intend to stay? ")))
        executive2 = (executive*executive1)
        if executive1 == 3.0 :
            executive_total = (executive*executive1*discount)
            executive = float(executive2-executive_total)
            executive_fin = format(executive, '.2f')
            print("Your total purchase will be",executive_fin,",enjoy your stay at Flappies.")
            return
        else:
            executive = 250.00
            executive_total = float(executive*executive1)
            executive_fin = format(executive_total, '.2f')
            print("Your total purchase will be",executive_fin,",enjoy your stay at Flappies.")
            return        

    print("The Junior suite runs 150.00 a night.")
    junior = input("Would you like the Junior suite? ")
    if junior == yes or yes1 :
        junior = 150.00
    else:
        junior1 = int(float(input("How many nights do you intend to stay? ")))
        junior2 = (junior*junior1)
        if junior1 == 3.0 :
            junior_total = (junior*junior1*discount)
            junior = float(junior2-junior_total)
            junior_fin = format(junior, '.2f')
            print("Your total purchase will be",junior_fin,",enjoy your stay at Flappies.")
            return
        else:
            junior = 150.00
            junior_total = float(junior*junior1)
            junior_fin = format(junior_total, '.2f')
            print("Your total purchase will be",junior_fin,",enjoy your stay at Flappies.")
            return

main()
```

I just don't understand why it won't work I'm stumped, I run it in idle it won't display executive and junior but it will run through grade with ease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if grande == yes or yes1:` is parsed as `if (grande == yes) or (yes1):`, which is always true since `yes1` is a non-empty string (which has a true value in a boolean test), so the correct test would be `if grande == yes or grande == yes1:`.

Now there's a much better way to handle this situation: normalize the user's input before the test:

```
grande = input("Would you like the Grande suite? ")
# .strip() : remove all whitespaces
# .lower() : convert to lowercase
grande = grande.strip().lower()

if grande == yes:
   # etc
```